# Plotting graph in Wolfram Mathmatica?

Tags: graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha

Which is the function that can plot me the graph K 7, 2 in mathematica? And after that to delete 2 edges?? 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Perhaps better to ask at [Mathematica.SE](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)...?

Comment: I also recommend to you to propose this question to the Mathematica SE community, however if you do, please specify on what you mean by the $K_{7,2}$ graph.

Comment: Bipartite graph K 7,2

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Mathematica has a great help with many examples. Also it does have its own community on StackExchange https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/ . You'd better address questions regarding Mathematica there

```
G1 = CompleteGraph[{7, 2}];
G2 = EdgeDelete[G1, {1 <-> 8, 2 <-> 8}];
GraphPlot[G1]
GraphPlot[G2]
```

Comment: EdgeDelete::graph: A graph object is expected at position 1 in EdgeDelete[Graph[CompleteGraph[{7,2}]],{1<->8,2<->8}]. >>

Comment: GraphPlot::grph: Graph[CompleteGraph[{7,2}]] is not a valid graph. >>

Comment: GraphPlot::grph: EdgeDelete[Graph[CompleteGraph[{7,2}]],{1<->8,2<->8}] is not a valid graph. >>

Comment: I've corrected my answer. Should work in Mathematica 8